# Cloning locally previous Heroku version

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

Hi guys I have been looking for an answer all over internet, 
But cannot find any answer that is helping me

I have a django app on heroku. I would like to donwload a previous version of my app. It is currently v62 and I would like to download V59 locally

I tried to rollback and then to do

```
heroku git:clone -a guarded-tor-21020
```

but it still download V62. 
What is the commande to download V59 please ?

Thx you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you've cloned your app you need to find a commit that corresponds to V59: `heroku releases -a guarded-tor-2102`. Look for line `V59 Deploy <git-commit>`.

Now do `git checkout <git-commit>`.

Answer (score 0):

first:
`heroku releases` to check the version you wish to rollback to 
second:
`heroku rollback v46` *46* can be any version of your choice 
third:
`git log --reflog` to see view and copy your commit id 
fourth:
`git checkout *commit id*`
fifth:
`heroku git:clone -a APP-NAME` to download current version